# Textalign in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, alignment, word-wrap

I have a short question about `Alignments`.

I am using a `TextBlock` in `XAML`.

When having a small window (`Widht > 200`)
and a long `Text` I have to enable `TextWrapping`.

No problem this far.

The problem is that when I want to align the `Text` in `Center` the wrapped part is aligned `Left` again.

**Is there a way to get rid of it or do I need to wrap it myself in code/use two `TextBlocks` ?**

> **Code:**

```
<TextBlock Margin="5"                
           VerticalAlignment="Center"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
           Text="This is a Test. This is a Test. This is a Test. This is a Test."
           TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```

> **How it looks like:**

[image]

> **What I need:**

Something like:

```
This is a Test. This is a Test. This is a Test.
                This is a Test.
```

Comment: Nothing wrong in my computer. Can your post your XAML code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `TextAlignment` attribute for aligning the text `Center`.

Adding this `Attribute` to the `TextBlock` will make it work

```
<TextBlock Margin="5"                
           VerticalAlignment="Center"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
           Text="This is a Test. This is a Test. This is a Test. This is a Test."
           TextAlignment="Center"
           TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the `TextAlignment` property to `Center`:

```
<TextBlock Margin="5"                
           VerticalAlignment="Center"
           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
           Text="This is a Test. This is a Test. This is a Test. This is a Test."
           TextWrapping="Wrap"
           TextAlignment="Center"/>
```